# The derivative of a decreasing function is _______

Tags: real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics

How would I go about proving this. A decreasing function f is defined as if x < y then for all x elements of f's domain, f(x) >= f(y). The example I am thinking of is a constant function whose derivative would be zero. Zero itself would be a constant function. A constant function can be both decreasing and increasing (not strict). Is this the answer to my question. If anyone can present a formal proof to my question that would be greatly appreciated. I tried doing it using the chain rule but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Hint: Use the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is decreasing then  $f'(x) \leq 0$. $-x^{3}$ is strictly decreasing on $\mathbb R$ but its derivative at $0$ is $0$, so we cannot say $f'(x) < 0$ for $f$ decreasing. To show that $f'(x) \leq 0$ you can just apply the definition of $f'(x)$.